# Create another object when I create an object in django model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, signals

When i create an object like:

bus_stop_1 = 4(Foreign Key)

bus_stop_2 = 7

then it should automatically create other object with

bus_stop_1 = 7

bus_stop_2 = 4

** time and distance would be the same
** BusStop is an model
My model

```
class ConnectedRoute(models.Model):
    bus_stop_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        BusStop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stop1')
    bus_stop_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        BusStop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stop2')
    distance = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have tried this my using save method and saving the ConnectedRoute but it been called recursively again and again.

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if the object is being created for the first time
        if not self.pk:
            # Create a new ConnectedRoute object with reversed bus stops
            reverse_connected_route = ConnectedRoute(
                bus_stop_1=self.bus_stop_2,
                bus_stop_2=self.bus_stop_1,
                distance=self.distance,
                time=self.time
            )
            reverse_connected_route.save()  # Save the reversed object
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you should *create* such record in the database. You can also simply *reason* (perform logic), by always filtering `bus_stop_1 = x` and `bus_stop_2 = y` *or* `bus_stop_1 = y` and `bus_stop_2 = x`.

Comment: I'm connecting bus stop's by using a ConnectedRoute table and database design would be like :
Consider you have 3 stop x--y--z  
and connection are: 
bs1=x  bs2=y,
bs1=y  bs2=z
In this case i can easy go from the x to z just by filtering bs1 alone(using graph model)

but when i needs to go from z to x the issue really start (i needs to filter using bs2), So in that case you can say that I should consider both bs1 and bs2 for filtering.

But there is other scenario like
bs1=x  bs2=y
bs1=z  bs2=y
In such an model i needs to write a lot of query(what if there is an junction)

Comment: well, the question is how you are querying for a route, by working with *undirected* edges, the algorithm will probably need a small change, but reasoning over undirected graphs is more or less equivalent to directed graphs, so you don't need per se to store the "back-connection" explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.get_or_create` - it creates new instance only if it does not exist,  like this:

```py
reverse_connected_route, created = ConnectedRoute.objects.get_or_create(
    bus_stop_1=self.bus_stop_2,
    bus_stop_2=self.bus_stop_1,
)
if (reverse_connected_route.distance, reverse_connected_route.time) != (self.distance, self.time):
    reverse_connected_route.distance = self.distance
    reverse_connected_route.time = self.time
    reverse_connected_route.save(update_fields=['distance', 'time'])
```

This if statement will prevent recursive calls
Maybe you will need to move `super().save()` at the top

---

Another way is to use db signals, like this:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=ConnectedRoute)
def trigger_reverse_route_creation(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created'] == True:
        sender.objects.get_or_create(
            bus_stop_1=instance.bus_stop_2,
            bus_stop_2=instance.bus_stop_1,
            defaults={'distance': instance.distance, 'time': instance.time}
        )
```

But this approach won't update second route distance and time if first one was updated. You'd have to add similar `if` statement here to update it.